# google Tag Manager datalayer payload difference

Tags: twilio, google-tag-manager, client-side, segment, google-datalayer

So when I was working with GMT to GA4, I was facing an issue such as the datalayer to which events are being pushed are a little different sometimes from one another. I am also loading GTM script using Twilio's segment.

[image: Payload with eventModel attribute]

[image: Payload without eventModel attribute]

There's another scenario where I created a trigger for Registration Submit and a Tag for it.
It triggers twice and one payload has eventModel and the other doesn't. What exactly is this eventModel??? where is it coming from? why some payload has and some don't?

Registration Submit without eventModel attribute,

[image]

Registration Submit with event model,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The one with `eventModel` is from gtag() library. Check your implementation which is causing the gtag.

The other one is pure datalayer push which looks like correct on this scenario.

Can you tell what is `loading GTM script using Twilio's segment`?

It should be sending data from GTM to segment but your words looks like the opposite way.

Comment: Got ya.

It's from website to segment to GTM. We have a segment source connected to our site and that source is connected to a GTM destination.

Comment: Oh I didn't try that. But I guess the `gtag` is from segment. So you might need to check is every event have these kind of situation.